# Does stickler have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, connotations

Does "**stickler**" in the following sentence have a negative connotation?

> My wife is stickler for detail.

If it is negative could you please give me an alternative which has a positive meaning?

Comment: No and anyway, "… stickler…" should always be "… a stickler…"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not negative in itself.  It means a person who insists on and displays a particular type of behaviour.  It could be used to mean that the person does so too much.  But the word itself doesn't have a negative connotation.

> The person I hire as my secretary has to be a real stickler for detail.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.  Sometimes being a stickler is exactly what is necessary to ensure accurate communication.